# google drive spreadsheet script TypeError: Cannot call method "getDataRange" of null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have read that many people had the same problem as me but all the solutions given to them dont work neither for me nor for many others.

When i deploy the script as a wep app and update it, as usual the following message appears:

```
Deploy as Web app
....
current wep app url:
......
Test web app for your "latest code" (link)
```

if i open the link given ("latest code") the web app works fine but if i open the url manually it says:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method "getDataRange" of null.
```

May be an authorize thing but im not sure.

```
var HEADER_SIZE=1;                                                   
function myFunction() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1_LpdPfvDnWCrFJ0NcbfTaUtQtsbD8Ph8xCNA-pTLuY0');
var s = ss.getSheetByName('tablaSordos');
var data  = s.getDataRange().getValues();                      
var total =(data.length)-(HEADER_SIZE);                
posicion donde termina el Header
var il =  (total+HEADER_SIZE);                                      
var users = [];                                                     

for(i=sl; i<il; i++){
users.push(data[i]);                                           
 }                                                                 

Logger.log(users);

var usersData = [];

for(i in users){

var row           = users[i];
var nombre        = row[0];
var direccion     = row[1];
var lat           = row[2];
var long          = row[3];
var territorio    = row[4];
var localidad     = row[5];
var observaciones = row[6];

var userData= new toObject(nombre,direccion,lat, long, territorio, localidad, observaciones);    //creamos un objeto, con cada usuario
Logger.log(userData);
usersData[i] = userData;
}

return usersData;

}

function toObject(nombre, direccion, lat, long, territorio, localidad, observaciones){
this.nombre = nombre;
this.direccion = direccion;
this.lat = lat;
this.long = long;
this.territorio = territorio;
this.localidad = localidad;
this.observaciones = observaciones;
 }

function doGet() {
var datos = myFunction();
return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(datos)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Comment: from the Google documentation:
" getSheetByName(name)

Returns a sheet with the given name. If multiple sheets have the same name, the leftmost one is returned. Returns null if there is no sheet with the given name."

I'm going to stick my neck out and say maybe 'tablaSordos' contains a typo? :)

Comment: Thanks for answering. What do you mean with a typo? "tablaSordos" is the only sheet and it is correctly spelled, that is why when i debug it no error comes up, instead if i put a wrong sheet name the "getDataRange" of null appears but this time in the debug mode. The original problem is that it doesnt return null when debugging nor opening the link given but when i use the url given to me.

Answer (score 1):

Well after reading a lot i found the poblem and solution:

1_Saving a new version of the script

2_Choosing the option:"Execute the app as: me" while deploying the web app.